# How Should I Set an Angular Material Stepper Step Completed Property in a Child Component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular v12

I am trying to control the ability to navigate an Angular Material Stepper using the header buttons. The ability to navigate away from the current Step is to be determined by some simple logic.

I have a parent component with a `ViewChild` to obtain a reference to its child component as follows:

```
  @ViewChild(WelcomeStepperComponent) welcomeStepperComponent!: WelcomeStepperComponent;
```

The child component has an Angular Material Stepper component within its template as follows:

```
  <mat-stepper id="welcome-stepper"
               #welcomeStepper
               orientation="horizontal"
               linear
               (selectionChange)="onStepChange($event)"
               style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

...

  </mat-stepper>
```

The child component code has a ViewChild to obtain a reference to the Stepper as follows:

```
  @ViewChild(MatStepper) stepper: MatStepper | null = null;
```

The `MatStepperNext` and `MatStepperPrevious` buttons' disabled state is determined by a function in the code and work fine. However, I discovered that you could still navigate using the Stepper's header buttons. I want to retain the ability to navigate using the header buttons but control when they enable navigation to match the state of the `MatStepperNext` and `MatStepperPrevious` buttons.

My approach has been create a function in the parent component to try and set the `completed` value for the current Step as follows.

I have a function which is called via the Stepper's `selectionChange` event and determines if the user is allowed to navigate to the next Step. Note: the first Step (selectedIndex: 0) should always allow the user to move to the next Step as it only displays some instructions:

```
  public onStepChange(event: StepperSelectionEvent): void 

      // Switch on the Stepper selectedIndex.
      switch (event.selectedIndex) {

        case 0: {

          this.welcomeStepperComponent.stepper.selected.completed = true;
          break;

        };

        case 1: {

          // Check if test is true.
          if (test === true) {
            this.welcomeStepperComponent.stepper.selected.completed = true;
          }
          else {
            this.welcomeStepperComponent.stepper.selected.completed = false;
          };

          break;

        };

        case 2: {

          // Check if test is true.
          if (test === true) {
            this.welcomeStepperComponent.stepper.selected.completed = true;
          }
          else {
            this.welcomeStepperComponent.stepper.selected.completed = false;
          };

          break;

        };

      }; // End switch

  };
```

What I am experiencing is that if I navigate through Steps 0, 1 to 2 this works. If I then navigate back from Step 2 to Step 1 the logic in the Switch case performs the `if (test === true)` and if this returns `false` and the `completed` property is set to `false` I can still navigate back to Step 2.

I have a feeling this may be related to the `editable` property which by default will be `true` for every Step. My expectation was that even though I have visited Step 2 (with `editable === true`) which would allow me to return, the fact that I was at Step 1 and `completed === false` was set I would not be allowed to navigate to Step 2. Perhaps I am wrong.

Any suggestions or advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel, use the cdk : https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/overview
good luck